# how to select two max function in oracle

Tags: oracle, select, max

I need to select max from two table here.  How can I do this? Here is my oracle code:

```
select t_order_demand.customer_name,
max(t_order_log.seq) as "seq",
max(t_order_log.extern_order_status) as "extern"
from t_order_demand,t_order_log
where t_order_demand.order_id=t_order_log.order_id
and t_order_demand.order_id like '%88%'
group by t_order_log.seq,t_order_log.extern_order_status,t_order_demand.customer_name;
```

The result is there are two customer names with seq column is 1 and the have two extern 0 and 2. i just want they show 1 customer name, 1 max seq and 1 max extern.  But how?  Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to remove the seq, extern_order from the `GROUP BY`
Also changed it to use explicit join

```
    select t_order_demand.customer_name,
    max(t_order_log.seq) as "seq",
    max(t_order_log.extern_order_status) as "extern"
    from t_order_demand
    JOIN t_order_log
    ON t_order_demand.order_id=t_order_log.order_id
    and t_order_demand.order_id like '%88%'
    group by t_order_demand.customer_name
```

if you want only one customer out of this set

```
SELECT * FROM  (
  select t_order_demand.customer_name,
  max(t_order_log.seq) as "seq",
  max(t_order_log.extern_order_status) as "extern"
  from t_order_demand
  JOIN t_order_log
  ON t_order_demand.order_id=t_order_log.order_id
  and t_order_demand.order_id like '%88%'
  group by t_order_demand.customer_name 
) WHERE ROW_NUM =1
```

Comment: @NikeAngreni, are you using second query? also i didn't get what you meant, can you show an example?

Comment: no, your query works.. it just my wrong, after i saw records of customer_name, there are record '3'. sorry for my mistake @RADAR